# Sending an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object to Rails App from Mobile device

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails API that takes an uploaded file as a parameter.  When I use postman to use the API, Postman will take the file and send it as a ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object as seen in the screenshot.  Is there a way I can do this using iOS?
[image]

Comment: You could consider the alternative: pass the base64 string of the image directly, then parse it server-side as a file. I do this using this [gem](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64)

Comment: The answer is going to depend on the language you are using to write your iOS app.

Comment: @ErvalhouS do you have an example of this?  Im trying it now and it seems like it's still just a string

Comment: Try `base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;"`, then send it. You have to take jpeg foto though.